# What is the Laurent Series for $\frac{1}{z^2}$ around z=0?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How do I get the Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{z^2}$ around $z=0$ ?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is; can you tell something about where you're stuck at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have it: $\frac1{z^2}$

Comment: That doens't make a lot of sense to me. I mean shouldn't the Laurent SERIES for it be a series?

Comment: A Laurent Serie is a serie of the type $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{-n} \frac1{z^n}$$ where $c_n\in \mathbb{C}$ for all $n$. Hence, $\frac1{z^2}$ is a Laurent serie because $c_{-2}=1$ and $c_n=0$ otherwise.